# Angular TypeScript: waiting for a void method to run before another method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, synchronization

I have a method in an Angular component that pulls data via `HttpClient` subscription, and assigns it to an attributes this.allData, then instantiates an empty dictionary of parameters based on this, to pass to a second function:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  allData: object[] = []
  activeData: object = {}

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData()
    this.makeRequestBasedOnData()
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(res => {
      for (let datum of res["data"]) {
        this.allData.push({
          "key": Object.keys(datum)[0],
          "values": Object.values(datum)[0]
        })
        this.activeData[Object.keys(datum)[0]] = ""
      }
    })
  }

  makeRequestBasedOnData() {
    let testParams = this.activeData
    console.log(testParam)
  }

}
```

I need these steps to happen sequentially. At the moment, logging the `testParams` in `makeRequestBasedOnData()` simply shows an empty object `{}`. When I try to return arbitrarily in the first method, I get a TypeScript error that you cannot assign a promise to type `void`.

How do I enforce synchronicity here even though neither method actually returns anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can return Observable from `getData` method and proceed with any other methods within subscribe:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getData().subscribe(() => this.makeRequestBasedOnData());
}

getData() {
  return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      // update allData
    })
  );
}
```

where:

- `pipe` method allows us to provide any kind of transformation with the data returned from `http.get(...)` call.
- `tap` is a rxjs operator for side-effects, meaning that we can do everything we want with the response without modifying Observable flow.

Comment: could explain what pipe and tap are doing here?